# LogLogPlot seems to not use same coordinates as Epilog?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

does anyone know how I can display this plot?

```
LogLogPlot[
 Piecewise[
  {
   {10^19 Exp[-10^12 t], 10^-19 <= t <= 10^-11 },
   {10^15 Exp[-10^9 t], 10^-11 <= t <= 10^-8},
   {10^11 t^(-1/2), 10^-8 <= t <= 10^36}
   }
  ],
 {t, 10^-19, 10^36},
 PlotRange -> {10^-13, 10^19}, 
 Epilog -> {Line[{10^-8, 10^15}, {10^-8, 10^-13}]}]
```

Trying to display it mathematica seems to give up somewhere on the second piecewise function, and the vertical line displays in a different position? Thanks!

PS Could someone explain why/how plots or graphics choose their coordinates, and how epilog chooses theirs? I figured out they don't seem to match, in particular for using LogLogPlot. many thanks!

Comment: You are missing a set of curly braces in your `Line`. It should be `Epilog -> {Line[{{10^-8, 10^15}, {10^-8, 10^-13}}]}`. This has nothing to do with machine precision

Comment: Silly me thanks @MarcoB

Comment: No problem. Glad it was an easy fix.

Comment: The line for some reason doesn't plot at 10^-8 with the curly braces; any idea why maybe?

Comment: Actually I figured it out, because the logplot uses different coordinates to Epilog, thanks!

Comment: @MKF To avoid closing this question, change the title to something like "LogLogPlot seems to use different coordinates for Epilog". Also edit the content to ask whether this behavior is logical. I think there is information in your finding.

Comment: Sure thing @Hector, thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 3):

The [Log plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html) log-transform the data (x, y or both, depending on the plot you choose – both for `LogLogPlot`) and change the tick labels to indicate the original (linear) scale. The whole plotting happens **after transformation of the coordinates**:

> LogLogPlot effectively generates a curve in which Log[f] is plotted against Log[x], but with tick marks indicating the original values of f and x.

As a result, you have to log-transform the coordinates in `Epilog` because Epilog is rendered after the original plot. Here the original plot without the `Epilog`:

```
loglogplot := 
  LogLogPlot[
   Piecewise[{{10^19 Exp[-10^12 t], 
      10^-19 <= t <= 10^-11}, {10^15 Exp[-10^9 t], 
      10^-11 <= t <= 10^-8}, {10^11 t^(-1/2), 
      10^-8 <= t <= 10^36}}], {t, 10^-19, 10^36}, 
   PlotRange -> {10^-13, 10^19}];
```

Now add the `Epilog` with the log-transformed coordinates:

```
Show[
 loglogplot,
 Epilog -> {Line[Log@{{10^-8, 10^15}, {10^-8, 10^-13}}]}
 ]
```

[image: LogLogPlot with Epilog]

`Show`ing the plot with another `Graphics` object gives the same result:

```
Show[
 loglogplot,
 Graphics[{Line[Log@{{10^-8, 10^15}, {10^-8, 10^-13}}]}]
 ]

(* same plot as above *)
```

Note how `Log`, being [Listable](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html), automatically threads over all coordinates within Line.